# Repartition of points in an ellipsoid PointCloud with Three.js

Tags: javascript, random, three.js, distribution

I have recently started to experiment with Three.js.
I tried to create an ellipsoid cloud of particles using the PointCloud object.

I generate random points using the parametric equation of an ellipsoid like so:

```
    var vertex = new THREE.Vector3();
    u = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;
    v = Math.random() * Math.PI;
    vertex.x = Math.random() * a * Math.cos(u) * Math.sin(v);
    vertex.y = Math.random() * b * Math.sin(u) * Math.sin(v);
    vertex.z = Math.random() * c * Math.cos(v);
```

But when I render the cloud, I notice that an unusual amount of particles agglomerate around the ellipsoid's axes.

I am wondering if this is linked with the distribution of the Math.random() function or am I missing something ? Please help me understand this.

You can have a look at it [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rVEBgV) and I made a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjT10.jpg) in case it doesn't look the same on your browser.

**Edit:** The code was modified as kindly suggested by @severin-pappadeux in order to avoid incorrectly distributed points, but the problem remains.

**Edit:**
I modified the part where I use Math.random() to set the length of the vertices, which was:

```
vertex.x = Math.random() * a * wx;
vertex.y = Math.random() * b * wy;
vertex.z = Math.random() * c * wz;
```

to:

```
vertex.x = (Math.random() + 0.1) * a * wx;
vertex.y = (Math.random() + 0.1) * b * wy;
vertex.z = (Math.random() + 0.1) * c * wz;
```

And the particles were more evenly distributed. What is even more intriguing is that it doesn't form a "cross-like hole" where the axes are, which I would expect since Math.random() + 0.1 will not yield any value below 0.1. So this little trick kind of solved my problem, even though I would still be interested in a good answer.

Comment: thats strange. Your pen didnt work, i've edited it [here](http://codepen.io/Astrak/pen/yNdLay). Im looking at it.

Comment: I've played with it a little. I've tried different things until simplify it to a disk (check the updated pen). I've came to a random angle+ random distance on the radius. Surprise, the distribution is also higher on... the axis. That is madness. Unless a reader gets it i suggest you to move your question to math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thanks for your research

Comment: I am starting to wonder if it is only an optical effect due to the way the particles are rendered instead of really being linked with the distribution of the points. I think that a statistical analysis may shed some light on this issue.

Comment: upvoted+star, i learnt much from this Q&As

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to create a cloud of random points uniformly distributed inside a 3D ellipsoid.

First, generate a random point inside a cube, and ignore points outside the embedded sphere.

```
vertex.x = 2 * Math.random() - 1;
vertex.y = 2 * Math.random() - 1;
vertex.z = 2 * Math.random() - 1;
if ( vertex.length() < 1 ) geometry.vertices.push( vertex );
```

You now will have uniform points inside a sphere. To create an ellipsoid, you scale the point cloud after you create it.

```
var pointCloud = new THREE.Points( geometry, material );
pointCloud.scale.set( a, b, c );
```

three.js r.86

Comment: This is essentially the same approach I proposed. Uniform-on-the-sphere and then scale and stretch it to ellipse. The only difference is that I use direct sampling (but with trigonometric functions), while you use acceptance-rejection method (but only using multiplications)

Comment: Well I tried your approach but I ended up with a cubic shape, see [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oXrweo?editors=001), the points do however look evenly distributed.

Comment: Its `vertex.length()` not `vertex.length`.

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux The approach in this answer generates points of _uniform density_ within the _volume_ of the sphere.

Comment: @WestLangley well, then it is not what was asked. Original question and implementation was about uniform points ON THE SURFACE of the ellipse

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux That is not my understanding of the poster's intention. Let the poster decide.

Comment: To me @WestLangley 's answer is correct (and simply smart), while @Severin Pappadeux had yet the correct approach and brought the information explaining the issue. Upvoted both. Thanks to you too as i was really scratching my head on it. May i add a final tip : in this script when asking N particles, will result in N*PI/6 particles because those outside the volume are not pushed. I would suggest the loop condition to be  `geometry.vertices.length <= N `, ignoring `i`

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, my intention was to have points of uniform density within the volume of the ellipsoid. @WestLangley Thank you for the correction. And for your answer. It actually looks really good using your technique. As to what differs from SeverinPappadeux 's method I have no idea.
Atrahasis I was going to point that out; I used a loop but it probably means a higher use of ressources. So I must either give up on deciding how many particles are in there or on optimisation.

Comment: Well I was able to generate 10^6 points in a reasonable time, which fits my need, so I will accept your answer, however I would like to leave it open a bit more to see if anyone can come up with an explanation.

Comment: Of why the problem occurs in the first place, using a more "classical" approach, with the trigonomic functions.

Comment: If you generate points on the surface and then scale uniformly in radius, you get a higher density of points near the origin. The two approaches are not "essentially similar". They result in a different distribution of points.

Answer (score 3):

Distribution is clearly not uniform in angles. What you see is equivalent to effects of http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpherePointPicking.html. One can try to build uniform-on-unit sphere vector and make intersection of it with ellipse to produce vertex. Something along the line

```
phi   = 2.0 * Math.PI * Math.random();
csth  = 2.0 * Math.random() - 1.0;
snth  = Math.sqrt((1.0 - csth)*(1.0 + csth));
wx = snth * Math.sin(phi);
wy = snth * Math.cos(phi);
wz = csth;
```

`(wx,wy,wz)` is unit vector. Build ray with distance `s*(wx,wy,wz)`. Intersect this ray coming from (0,0,0) with ellipse, and find your vertex

UPDATE

didn't realize question was about uniform in the given volume. Anyway to get uniform in the unit sphere one has to add radius sampling:

```
r = Math.pow( Math.random(), 1.0/3.0 ); // is there cubic root sqrt3() function?
```

Then point within sphere would be `(r*wx, r*wy, r*wz)` and could be scaled accordingly with `(a, b, c)`

Comment: Thank you for bringing this interesting point up. I edited the [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rVEBgV) as you suggested, but the problem seems to remain. Any ideas?

Comment: @GaussianBlurs It is not clear to me, you edited the question, so do you still have the issue or not?

Comment: @GaussianBlurs and I don't see anything on codepen link you provided - using Chrome

Comment: Yes, the javascript console says "Refused to execute script [...] because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled".
No idea why this happens, so I did a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8x38gj63/), tell me if it works.

Comment: So I pasted OrbitControl.js into the pen and it worked. But there's a long way to scroll before getting to the important part...
Also, it doesn't look the same at all on Chrome / Mac OS X Yosemite as it does on Firefox / Win 7

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using @WestLangley's solution, which was implemented like this (as suggested by @ Atrahasis) :

```
while(geometry.vertices.length < 20000) {
    var vertex = new THREE.Vector3();
    vertex.x = 2 * Math.random() - 1;
    vertex.y = 2 * Math.random() - 1;
    vertex.z = 2 * Math.random() - 1;
    if(vertex.length() < 1) geometry.vertices.push(vertex);
}
```

You can see the full code [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rVEZGp) (it looks better on Firefox than on Chrome, from what I saw)

Bonus tip: Importing raw js files in Codepen/JSFiddle etc from Github will not work on Chrome because the file's MIME type is 'text/plain' and so the browser does not execute it. The trick is to replace the `http://raw.github.com/` part with `http://rawgit.com/` so for OrbitControls.js, I changed `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js` to `https://rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js` and it worked !

Thank you @SeverinPappadeux for your interesting contribution.